# display tool tip over disabled select filed in html

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I need to pop up tool tip over disabled select field, i am currently using angularjs v1.3.7, using angular-foundation tooltip to display tooltip content.

please suggest me possible solutions.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Can you include any code you've used? What's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't try it in the that version of Angular but I remember it was not working. You can always wrap your select field in a div and add your tooltip on it instead of your field.

```
<div popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" style="display:inline-block;width:200px;">
        <select disabled>
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

See a [demo](http://plnkr.co/unjLT7WYtD87fp10Vfmw).